# how to deliver the standard err immediately to parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parameters

the following simple script will display dialog GUI with 3 question 
and need to choose option 1/2/3

the problem is that I want to store the answer 1/2/3 in parameter not in file and then I take the val from the file

what I want is to deliver the standard err immediately to parameter

please advice how to set the standard err ( 2> ) in to parameter?

```
#!/bin/bash



  dialog    --backtitle "red-hat"  --title "[ computers ]" \
        --menu "Please choose an option:" 15 55 5  \
           1 "erase disk" \
           2 "clean disk" \
           3 "break disk" 2>/temp


       parameter=$(cat /temp )
```

what I want to get is like that:

```
    parameter=$( 2> )  .. something like this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$()` and a bit of redirection:

```
parameter=$(dialog    --backtitle "red-hat"  --title "[ computers ]" \
    --menu "Please choose an option:" 15 55 5  \
       1 "erase disk" \
       2 "clean disk" \
       3 "break disk" 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Note that order is important. `2>&1` dups fd 1 to fd 2. `>/dev/null` redirects fd 1 so you don't get any of the output written on stdout.

---

In this case, dialog's stdout still needs to be the tty in order to display to the user. I would recommend you follow [this guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/040) and use the following redirection instead:

```
parameter=$(dialog    --backtitle "red-hat"  --title "[ computers ]" \
    --menu "Please choose an option:" 15 55 5  \
       1 "erase disk" \
       2 "clean disk" \
       3 "break disk" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

Comment: GREATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process substitution` to capture stderr in a variable in a subshell:

```
ls *.exe 2> >(read -r err; echo "ERROR :: $err")
ERROR :: ls: cannot access *.exe: No such file or directory
```

OR **without creating sub shell**:

```
read -u 2 -r err 2< <(dialog    --backtitle "red-hat"  --title "[ computers ]" \
        --menu "Please choose an option:" 15 55 5  \
           1 "erase disk" \
           2 "clean disk" \
           3 "break disk" 2>&1)

echo "ERROR :: $err"
```